# how to make dompdf handle twig page

Tags: php, twig, dompdf

I have to convert a dynamic page written with TWIG to PDF. I am unable to make him interpret the TWIG code, every php, html output is rendered but TWIG is ignored. Can you tell me if there is a solution that is not "to rewrite the same template in php" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the render function? it outputs html so that you can pass it in your DomPDF.

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
'cache' => '/path/to/compilation_cache',
));
$dompdf->load_html($twig->render('index.html', array('name' => 'Fabien')));
$dompdf->render(); 
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```

If you are under Symfony

```
$dompdf->load_html($this->renderView('index.html', array('name' => 'Fabien')));
$dompdf->render(); 
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```