# how do I use loader for twig templates using dompdf

Tags: twig, dompdf, slim

I am using dompdf and twig

I had some success with
[how to make dompdf handle twig page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561250/how-to-make-dompdf-handle-twig-page)

however I cannot use the loader to load the templates using filesystem

given

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
'cache' => '/path/to/compilation_cache',
));
```

I want to impliment the loader above this as

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates');
```

however this does not work

if I change loader simply to

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_String();
```

it only renders the page name

so on the above mentioned page - how do I add loader to get templates to display?

Thank you in advance

**More Info**

Using Slim Framework but I do not think it is an issue

having these lines

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_String();
```

dompdf works but just renders the page name

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('/home/sites/******/public_html/templates');
```

I then get

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMText::getAttribute() in /home/sites/******/app/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/include/cellmap.cls.php on line 437
```

confused - using slim and twig why can dompdf not accept the html as the other page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561250/how-to-make-dompdf-handle-twig-page) suggests?

Comment: Might be more reliable to use something like `__DIR__.'/relative/path/to/templates'`

Comment: **Thank you for your response** - the templates path is registered in the slim initialization and works elsewhere, I put the full path in and it works elsewhere but not with dompdf. I suppose I just need the $loader line used in _**[this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561250/how-to-make-dompdf-handle-twig-page)**_ I will add slim as a tag

Comment: added more info following being able to see the error

Comment: The error may indicate some structural problems with your HTML. Try validating the HTML you're feeding to dompdf.

Comment: **thank you** it looks like Brian may well be right - got to spend some time sorting out the html generated interacting with mine. I will report back in a day or 2